# Rails: How I can get yesterday's date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get yesterday's date?

maybe:

```
@get_time_now    = Time.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') / 86400
```

or

```
@get_time_now    = Time.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') - 1.day
```

or

```
@get_time_now    = Time.now. / 86400
```

86400 = 1 day, right? (60 * 60 * 24)

Comment: not all days are 86400 seconds long (boundaries of daylight savings changes are +/- 1 hour).

Answer (score 189, accepted):

#### Rails

For a date object you could use:

```
Date.yesterday
```

Or a time object:

```
1.day.ago
```

#### Ruby

Or outside of rails:

```
require 'date'

Date.today.prev_day
```

Comment: **Time.now - 1.day** also works, just mentioning for completeness.

Comment: @Gazler: Not quite. As Tim Peters has mentioned above, 24 hours isn't always the same as a day.

Comment: Date.yesterday considers timezone and will not always give the same answer as Date.today - 1.days.

Comment: This assumes rails and not ruby. Not the best suggestion.

Comment: Agreed, this is Rails, not Ruby.

Comment: [`.prev_day` \[`.prev_month`/`.prev_year`\] also takes an arg](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-prev_day), so you can do `Date.today.prev_day(n=3)` to get 3 days ago (or `DateTime.now.prev_day(3)`).

Answer (score 16):

After trying `1.day.ago` and variants on it:

```
irb(main):005:0> 1.day.ago
NoMethodError: undefined method `day' for 1:Fixnum
```

if found that `Date.today.prev_day` works for me:

```
irb(main):016:0> Date.today.prev_day
=> #<Date: 2013-04-09 ((2456392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: You probably arent using Rails. ActiveSupport gives you this functionality

Comment: Note you can also do basic date arithmetic, for example `Date.today - 1`

Answer (score 15):

```
Time.now - (3600 * 24)   # or Time.now - 86400
```

or

```
require 'date'

Date.today.prev_day
```

Comment: Most clear for vanilla ruby `Time.now - (3600 * 24)`

Comment: `Time.now - (3600 * 24)` is not yesterday. Not all days have 24 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby 2.1.2 Native Time

Answer:

```
Time.at(Time.now.to_i - 86400)
```

Proof:

```
2.1.2 :016 > Time.now
 => 2014-07-01 13:36:24 -0400 
2.1.2 :017 > Time.now.to_i
 => 1404236192 
2.1.2 :018 > Time.now.to_i - 86400
 => 1404149804 
2.1.2 :019 > Time.at(Time.now.to_i - 86400)
 => 2014-06-30 13:36:53 -0400
```

One Day of Seconds.

86400 = 1 day (60 * 60 * 24)

Comment: Thanks to daylight savings, subtracting 86400 won't always do it.

Answer (score 6):

Use Date.today - 1.days.

Date.yesterday depends on the current time and your offset from GMT

```
1.9.3-p125 :100 > Date.today
 => Wed, 29 Feb 2012 
1.9.3-p125 :101 > Date.yesterday
 => Wed, 29 Feb 2012 
1.9.3-p125 :102 > Date.today - 1.days
 => Tue, 28 Feb 2012
```

Answer (score 5):

use DateTime.now - 1

```
1.9.3p194 :040 > DateTime.now
 => Mon, 18 Nov 2013 17:58:45 +0530 
1.9.3p194 :041 > DateTime.now - 1
 => Sun, 17 Nov 2013 17:58:49 +0530
```

or DateTime.yesterday

```
1.9.3p194 :042 > DateTime.yesterday
 => Sun, 17 Nov 2013
```

or we can use `rails` `advance` method for `Time` and `DateTime`

```
1.9.3p194 :043 > Time.now.advance(days: -1)
 => 2013-11-17 17:59:36 +0530
1.9.3p194 :044 > DateTime.now.advance(days: -1)
 => Sun, 17 Nov 2013 17:59:49 +0530
```

`advance` method also provides this options `:years, :months, :weeks, :days, :hours, :minutes, :seconds`

[DateTime advance method](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/advance)

[Time advance method](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/advance)

Answer (score 3):

You can just subtract 86400 from a `Time` object to get one day before.  If you are using Rails, or have ActiveSupport included, you can replace 86400 with `1.days`.

If you're using a `Date` object, and not a `Time` object, just subtract 1 from it.

To check if one date/time is before/after another, just compare the two objects like you would do for numbers:

```
DateTime.parse("2009-05-17T22:38:42-07:00") < DateTime.parse("2009-05-16T22:38:42-07:00")
# => false
```

Comment: Thanks to daylight savings, subtracting 86400 won't always do it.